# How I can disable anchor clickable on smartWizard plugin?

Tags: javascript, jquery, smart-wizard

I use this code, but the anchors are always clickable when I click on the next button. I want to disable the anchors step navigation. How I can do this? This is my init function...

```
$('#smartwizard').smartWizard({

    onFinish: function () {
        $('#formTemplates').submit();
    },
    anchorSettings: {
        anchorClickable: false, // Enable/Disable anchor navigation
        enableAllAnchors: false, // Activates all anchors clickable all times
        markDoneStep: true, // add done css
        enableAnchorOnDoneStep: false // Enable/Disable the done steps navigation
    },      
});
```

Answer (score 0):

`$('.anchor a').addClass('disabled');
$('.anchor a').unbind("click");`

I guess you might be using a version that has not implemented yet that feature.
As a temporally solution I managed to restraint links by using this code.